# Measure edge strength in OpenCV, magnitude of gradient

Tags: python, algorithm, opencv, computer-vision

I have an application where I need to check the focus of a camera.  For this, I want to measure edge strength (magnitude of gradient) in several predefined locations on a single axis (1D).  The image target will be a simple printout of black objects on a while background.

I am using OpenCV with Python.  I know there are several edge detection algorithms within OpenCV like Canny, Sobel, laplace but all of these are to filter the image.  I want to actually measure the strength of an edge.  Are there any algorithms within OpenCV that can provide this? Or do I just write my own algorithm to measure edge strength?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can compute the magnitude like:

1. Compute `dx` and `dy` derivatives (using `cv::Sobel`)
2. Compute the magnitude `sqrt(dx^2 + dy^2)` (using `cv::magnitude`)

This is a simple C++ code that compute the magnitude of the gradient. You can easily port to Python, since it's just a few calls to OpenCV functions:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
using namespace cv;

int main()
{
    //Load image
    Mat3b img = imread("path_to_image");

    //Convert to grayscale
    Mat1b gray;
    cvtColor(img, gray, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

    //Compute dx and dy derivatives
    Mat1f dx, dy;
    Sobel(gray, dx, CV_32F, 1, 0);
    Sobel(gray, dy, CV_32F, 0, 1);

    //Compute gradient
    Mat1f magn;
    magnitude(dx, dy, magn);

    //Show gradient
    imshow("Magnitude", magn);
    waitKey();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is excellent, but how to I get one resultant value for the strength of the edge? The magnitude returns a list of values, do these values just need to be averaged?

Comment: also take a look [here](http://answers.opencv.org/question/5395/how-to-calculate-blurriness-and-sharpness-of-a-given-image/)

Comment: @Chad What you get from magnitude is a matrix of the size o the image. At each position within that matrix you have the corresponding edge strength for this position. Averaging this matrix would give you the average edge strength of the whole image.

Comment: @Chad, you can get the average magnitude of an edge using the edge as mask over the magnitude matrix. You can then average only the magnitude values under the mask.

Comment: Thanks for the info, after reviewing it more I am going to sum the results.  Thanks @sturkmen

Comment: perhaps it may seem unnecessary but anyone could suggest a better name for [this function](http://answers.opencv.org/question/5395) instead of contrast_measure

Comment: @sturkmen I don't know if it is formally correct, but [net_force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Net_force) seems cool :D

Comment: @Miki i found the correct answer `calcBlurriness` for details [see](http://answers.opencv.org/question/5395)

Answer (score 6):

Here's a Python version:

```
def getGradientMagnitude(im):
    "Get magnitude of gradient for given image"
    ddepth = cv2.CV_32F
    dx = cv2.Sobel(im, ddepth, 1, 0)
    dy = cv2.Sobel(im, ddepth, 0, 1)
    dxabs = cv2.convertScaleAbs(dx)
    dyabs = cv2.convertScaleAbs(dy)
    mag = cv2.addWeighted(dxabs, 0.5, dyabs, 0.5, 0)
    return mag

mag = getGradientMagnitude(im)
```

Comment: This code is incorrect. It computes `0.5 * abs(dx) + 0.5 * abs(dy)`. What is needed is `sqrt(dx**2 + dy**2)`. The function `cv2.magnitude` will compute this: `mag = cv2.magnitude(dx, dy)`.